# Rails 5: Add belongs_to association with custom name to model, and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `User` model and a `Question` model.

I want to add a `belongs_to :user` association to the `Question` model, but I want that association to be called `author`. For example, I would call `question.author` rather than `question.user`.

Obviously this requires two steps:

1. The association in the models/question.rb
2. The migration (note both the user and question tables already exist)

Surprisingly I haven't found the single, conventional method of doing this in Rails 5 in a different answer.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
rails g migration add_user_to_questions user:references
rails db:migrate
```

Ideally, you also open the generated migration and change the `add_reference` by adding options which you need. Example of more "full" add_reference:

```
add_references(
  :user,
  null: false,
  index: {name: "custom_index_name_if_needed"},
  type: :integer,
  foreign_key: {
    to_table: "public.my_users_table",
    on_delete: :cascade # ensure the row is deleted when user is deleted from DB
  }
)
```

Then in model:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord # or ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! One more question.. how come sometimes we use `bin/rails ...`, `rails ...`, and `rake ...`?

Comment: @rigdonmr sorry, starting from rails 5 both should be `rails` - they changed it

Comment: it will create `add_reference :questions, :user, foreign_key: true` in migration's file.