# Rails: belongs_to/has_many with non-id foreign/primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with a legacy database where a `story` `belongs_to` a `user` and a `user` `has_many` `stories`.  The problem is that it's all uploaded data, so they can't connect with the `id` field like Rails usually does.

Here's the structure for the `Story` table:

```
  create_table "stories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "authorId"
    ...
  end
```

And here's the structure for the `User` table:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.integer "uid"
    ...
end
```

I need to somehow join them so that the `story`'s `authorId` connects to matching values for a `user`'s `uid`.

I've looked at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047920/rails-belongs-to-with-custom-column-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375202/rails-5-add-belongs-to-association-with-custom-name-to-model-and-migration), as well as the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference), but I can't find model code that works.

Right now what I have is, for `story.rb`:

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'authorId'
end
```

And for `user.rb` (I'm using Devise.):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :trackable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :stories, class_name: "Story", foreign_key: 'uid'
end
```

Can anyone see how to get these models properly linked up in a `belongs_to/has_many`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe by your post that you cannot update the AuthorID to user_id, and change uid to id. After that, you would have a clean relationship.

But, try to define the primary_key and foreign_key and customize your association:

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, primary_key: "uid", foreign_key: "authorId"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stories, primary_key: "authorId"
end
```

or this:

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, primary_key: "uid"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stories, primary_key: "authorId", foreign_key: "uid"
end
```

I think this maybe works.

Comment: The first customization worked perfectly!  Thank you!